# Cannot install nextcloud despite correct permissions

Tags: centos, permissions, apache-httpd

I have just spun up a CentOS 7 VM to host an instance of **nextcloud**, however, next-cloud constantly complains that the web-server cannot write into the config directory.

My permissions are as follows, does anyone have any thoughts?

```
total 156
drwxrwxr-x. 14 root apache  4096 Jul 18 10:34 .
drwxrwxr-x.  3 root apache    39 Jul 27 16:31 ..
drwxrwxr-x. 29 root apache  4096 Jul  5 05:10 3rdparty   
drwxrwxrwx. 30 root apache  4096 Jul  5 05:09 apps
-rw-rw-r--.  1 root apache  8065 Jul  5 05:08 AUTHORS
drwxrwxrwx.  2 root apache    46 Jul  5 05:08 config
-rw-rw-r--.  1 root apache  3695 Jul  5 05:08 console.php
-rw-rw-r--.  1 root apache 34520 Jul  5 05:08 COPYING-AGPL
drwxrwxr-x. 16 root apache  4096 Jul 18 10:32 core
-rw-rw-r--.  1 root apache  5919 Jul  5 05:08 cron.php
-rw-rw-r--.  1 root apache 32727 Jul  5 05:08 db_structure.xml
-rw-rw-r--.  1 root apache  2492 Jul  5 05:08 .htaccess
-rw-rw-r--.  1 root apache   179 Jul  5 05:08 index.html
-rw-rw-r--.  1 root apache  2027 Jul  5 05:08 index.php
drwxrwxr-x.  3 root apache    63 Jul  5 05:08 l10n
drwxrwxr-x.  5 root apache    80 Jul  5 05:08 lib
-rwxrwxr-x.  1 root apache   283 Jul  5 05:08 occ
drwxrwxr-x.  2 root apache    69 Jul  5 05:08 ocs
drwxrwxr-x.  2 root apache    41 Jul  5 05:08 ocs-provider
-rw-rw-r--.  1 root apache  2969 Jul  5 05:08 public.php
-rw-rw-r--.  1 root apache  4599 Jul  5 05:08 remote.php
drwxrwxr-x.  5 root apache    57 Jul  5 05:08 resources
-rw-rw-r--.  1 root apache    26 Jul  5 05:08 robots.txt
drwxrwxr-x. 12 root apache  4096 Jul  5 05:08 settings
-rw-rw-r--.  1 root apache  1835 Jul  5 05:08 status.php
drwxrwxr-x.  3 root apache    33 Jul  5 05:08 themes
drwxrwxr-x.  7 root apache  4096 Jul  5 05:10 updater
-rw-rw-r--.  1 root apache   163 Jul  5 05:08 .user.ini
-rw-rw-r--.  1 root apache   235 Jul 18 10:34 version.php
```

this makes no sense because I can confirm that in `../httpd/conf/httpd.conf` apache is running as user `apache`and no matter how I configure ownership I get the same nag.

Comment: What user are you running the webserver (apache) as?  What error it is giving you?  Are you sure it is `httpd` that is giving you the error?

Comment: According to httpd.conf, Apache is running under user and group 'apache'. The webpage, is telling me the web server cannot write into the config/ directory which is owned and write able by user and group Apache

Comment: But *how* it is telling you?  What process is telling you?  In the shell?  In the log?

Comment: Through the web browser. If I visit the folder through a web browser nextcloud is stored in nextcloud tells me it can't write.

Comment: And you can place a file in there (by hand, on the server) and then read it through nextcloud, right?  (that is to test that you are reading/writing the directory you believe you are trying to read/write)

Comment: Sorry Perhaps I'm being confusing. I'm trying to run the nextcloud installer. all the files are there, when i visit the webpage the php files are being parse and the application is "running." however, Through the webpage (home.ozpri.com/nextcloud) I am being told that the installer cannot write into the config /directory of the nextcloud application. Does this many any sense?

Comment: Sorry for that, understanding someone through the internet is not easy sometimes.  I cannot tell you what nextcloud installer is doing, but I can certainly help with debugging ideas. nextcloud installer runs inside the webserver and it cannot be running in a different way than any other PHP script (it requires php so it must be running through `mod_php`).  You could make a PHP script that writes to a file in the same directory, and that would be much easier to debug.  Even a simple `file_put_contents()` will do.  Also, i'm making a chat link for us.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43100/discussion-between-grochmal-and-user502301).